# MySql connector with Entity Framework: Comparing Char(36) GUIDs in a LINQ Where clause

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq-to-entities, mysql-connector

I think the title pretty much nails it.

I am using a Char(36) in a MySql table which automatically gets recognized as a GUID when using the Entity Framework.

Inserting the GUID is no problem, but trying to compare it in a WHERE clause is a nightmare.

What I've tried:

First of all I've tried a `WHERE element.GUID == GuidToCompare`.

This resulted in `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Object CompareObjectEqual(System.Object, System.Object, Boolean)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

Then I tried to just convert the value to String, like so:

`WHERE element.GUID.ToString() == GuidtoCompare.ToString()`

This resulted in this error: `LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

So either way, I just can't compare them. I am ready to just not use GUIDs if they don't work out.

Comment: what's element.GUID's type? Guid or String?

Comment: Well, one of these isn't a GUID, or L2E wouldn't be seeing `CompareObjectEqual`. L2E certainly *does* support comparing two GUIDs directly. Check your types.

Comment: @Craig Oh good lord... I know what was wrong, see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know what was wrong: It was just a stupid error of myself.

The thing with comparing guids was quite correct, this was not the part that gave the error. Actually a later part in the same LINQ query fired the error. It compared `ProviderUserKey (Object)` to `ID (int)`. The `ProviderUserKey` is essentialls an int, I just had to explicitly state it's type ( `CType(Object, Integer)` in VB.NET or `(int)Object` in C#)